# Make File Name the default Finder Window Search in Snow Leopard (10.6.7)?

Tags: search, finder

How does one get Finder Window Search in Snow Leopard (10.6.7) to default to *File Name* instead of *Contents*?

Please note that this is not the same as changing the default setting to File Name for separate Search Windows invoked with <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>F</kbd>. The `default_smart.plist` method used for that (described in the *Make search by file name default* in Finder thread) seems to have no effect when the search is initiated by entering text in the search field at the upper right of each folder window, which is what I really need/want (so I can search the current folder instead of the entire computer).